# Is it possible that x-wings, y-wings, a-wings, and TIEs fought in the Battle of Hoth?

Tags: star-wars, battle-of-hoth, star-wars-battlefront

The canon book *Battlefront: Twilight Company* reveals that the Empire used at least one clone turbo tank at the Battle of Hoth. This basically says that the events of the Battle of Hoth are not limited to what we see in *The Empire Strikes Back*. The book is a tie-in to the semi-canon game *Star Wars Battlefront*. Due to the strange canonicity status of the game, is it possible that the ships that are seen in the battle actually fought there?

Comment: Haven't read the book - but we see X-Wings flying cover for the escaping transports in the movie - the Star Destroyers would have deployed their TIEs to deal with the rebel fighters - I don't recall seeing any Y-Wings in ESB but that doesn't mean they're not there. The A-Wings were not introduced (out of universe) until RotJ, but I'm not sure when the rebels started using them in-universe. In any event - the rebels would have flown any combat capable ship into the fight to help cover the transports.

Comment: In the Star Wars Rebels TV series (which is canon), a-wings were used by the early rebellion four years before the Battle of Yavin.

Comment: Haven't watched those either (so far behind on my watching/reading of things) - so, there's nothing to say the rebels didn't have A-Wings at Hoth, so they could very well have flown into combat there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rebel forces.

Canonically, the Rebels didn't involve their X-wings in the on-planet battle, with all of their fighters being used to guard the fleeing transports. It would also appear that their other craft types (A- and B-Wings) simply weren't present during the battle at all, and were elsewhere at the time, presumably with the bulk of the Rebel fleet.

> The rebels were still on Hoth, but all of their critical equipment had
> already been loaded. Thirty rebel transports would have to run the
> Imperial blockade and escape to hyperspace, but Rieekan had planned
> for that: Echo Base would briefly lower the shield to fire blasts from
> its ion cannon at the Star Destroyers overhead, allowing X-wings to
> escort the transports to safety. Meanwhile, snowspeeders and ground
> forces would delay the Imperial ground assault as long as possible.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy)</sup></sub>

### Empire Forces

General Veers *did* use TIEs to guard his dropships, anticipating X-Wing attacks, but when those didn't materialise, and mindful that the TIEs weren't much use due to the cold conditions, he ordered their withdrawal.

> Veers worried that X-wings would swarm his AT-ATs before
> they could deploy from their dropships, so he used nimble
> Gozanti-class cruisers to deliver the walkers, escorted by
> TIEs. But Blizzard Force landed unmolested at the Moorsh
> Moraine—the X-wings had other orders, which saw them
> providing support to the convoy evacuating the planet.
> It was also quickly apparent that Hoth’s frigid winds robbed
> the TIEs of their maneuverability, and Veers ordered them
> back into space.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy)</sup></sub>

Comment: I've made fun of Disney canon for being half-baked before, but I gotta say that this level of detail is mighty impressive.

Comment: @Harabeck - This particular in-universe book is proving to be very useful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Legends provides some extra assault craft used during the battle.
Imperials: "A6s were deployed in the Battle of Hoth" (clone turbo tanks)
according to one of the "Rogue Squadron" games, tie bombers were used, and 74-Z speeder bikes were also deployed. X wings were obviously shown escorting the GR-75 cruisers, Many ISD's were present along with an SSD, many rebel ships would be leaving, and my personal favorite: The "M class starfighters, cobbled together from Y wing bombers. [image]